# Angular 5, Angular Material and Electron

Tags: angular, angular-material, electron

I've recently started a project with Angular 5 and Electron. I have it running fine without using angular material, but once I tried using angular material (following all the instructions online) it gives me a new warning;

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1112:164-170 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

I have looked thoroughly through my code and re-done the instructions online. Nothing seems to have worked. I can't find anyone on stack-overflow whose also had this problem.

Comment: When does this happen? Running `ng serve` or `electron .`? Anyway, might be a version mismatch. Tried updating all your angular packages?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10034)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of angular material are you using? Because the latest one (6.x.x) is not fully compatible with Angular 5. I solved these kind of Warnings downgrading `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material` to `5.2.2` .